# Using .NET Regular Expression, match any string with exactly 9 digits

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to create a regex expression to match any string that has exactly 9 digits.  the digits can exist anywhere in the string.

For example, if you passed in the following strings, you'd get a match:
123456789
123aeiou456abc789

These strings would fail to provide a match
12345678
1234567890

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
@"^(\D*\d){9}\D*$"
```

Or use this improved version. It assumes that you only want to match 0-9 and not other characters that represent digits in other languages. It also uses a non-capturing group to improve performance:

```
"^(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){9}[^0-9]*$"
```

Here's a breakdown of what it means:

```
^        Start of string.
(?:      Start a non-capturing group.
[^0-9]*  Match zero or more non-digits.
[0-9]    Match exactly one digit.
)        Close the group.
{9}      Repeat the group exactly 9 times.
[^0-9]*  Match zero or more non-digits.
$        End of string.
```

Here's a testbed for it:

```
string regex = "^(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){9}[^0-9]*$"
string[] tests = {
                     "123456789",
                     "123aeiou456abc789",
                     "12345678",
                     "1234567890"
                 };
foreach (string test in tests)
{
    bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(test, regex); 
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", test, isMatch);
}
```

Results:

```
123456789: True
123aeiou456abc789: True
12345678: False
1234567890: False
```

Comment: +1 - pretty much what I would have posted. Note, however, that `\d` *may* match other digits than 0..9 in Unicode environments (such as 0xFF10..0xFF19).

Comment: The capturing groups have to be improved, but yes, it works this way. The result will be like 18 groups, of which 9 contain a single digit ... +1

Comment: RE:Lucero's, if the Unicode bit is a problem, the `\d` could always be replaced with `[0-9]`.

Comment: @eidylon, I know, it was a hint because many people believe that `\d` will just match the ASCII 0..9, which is not true. The question states 9 digits, which is what the expression of Mark handles, but it would also match ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩ for instance.

Comment: @tanascius, no, "only" 1 group with 9 captures. And it is easy to get rid of them by using `(?:` to open the group.

Comment: I've included some suggestions from the comments in the answer, thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

check out the website

http://www.regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx

I found it tobe very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take: `^[^0-9]*[0-9]{9}[^0-9]*$`

FWIW, there is a REALLY cool little app to help you build RegEx's which will parse them and explain what your expression is doing in plain English as well as providing an actual UI to help you add expressions you may not be very familiar with. [Check out Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm).

Comment: this does not match `123aeiou456abc789`, where the digits are spread over the input

Comment: Ah yes, this one does look for them all contiguous. RegEx withdrawn.

Comment: Thanks eidylon - expresso is now in my toolkit