# any combination of digits ignoring spaces which are > than x or < x

Tags: regex

Not the best at regex
looking for an combination of digits with spaces like this

\s*([0-9]+)\s*([0-9]+)\s*([0-9]+)

but only when the total digits is 7-9 in length (not including the spaces?)

so these would match

```
12345678
123456789
1234567
123 4567  8
12   3456789
12 3456  7
```

these wouldn't

```
123456
1234567890
1234 5 6
123 4567  890
12   345678900
12 3456
```

Comment: What is the regex flavor? In .NET, Python PyPi regex, or with modern JS (ECMAScript 2018+) you can use `(?<![0-9] *)[0-9](?: *[0-9]){6,8}(?! *[0-9])` / `(?<!\d *)\d(?: *\d){6,8}(?! *\d)` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/CRNLer/1)).

Comment: Thanks for the replyusing it in postgres POSIX

Comment: Oh yes and thank you that's amazing!! Not sure how it works but I have wasted hours on this.

Comment: It won't work in PostgreSQL.

Comment: it runs in postgres

Comment: Good, I posted the solution with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from Mark Bryers [answer on a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2883785/2325377).

You can use `^(?:[\s]*[0-9]){7,9}[^0-9]*$`

This breaks down as:

```
^        Start of string.
(?:      Start a non-capturing group.
[\s]*    Match zero or more spaces.
[0-9]    Match exactly one digit.
)        Close the group.
{7,9}    Repeat the group at least 7 and at most 9 times.
[^0-9]*  Match zero or more non-digits.
$        End of string.
```

I created a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1f8711/1) that demonstrates it's use.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with PosgreSQL 9.6, you can use lookbehinds with variable-width regex patterns, and thus you can use

```
(?<![0-9] *)[0-9](?: *[0-9]){6,8}(?! *[0-9])
(?<!\d *)\d(?: *\d){6,8}(?! *\d)
```

or - if the strings are not multiline

```
(?<!\d\s*)\d(?:\s*\d){6,8}(?!\s*\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CRNLer/1). *Details*:

- `(?<!\d\s*)` - immediately on the left, there should not be a digit followed with zero or more whitespaces
- `\d` - a digit
- `(?:\s*\d){6,8}` - six, seven or eight sequences of zero or more whitespaces and then a digit
- `(?!\s*\d)` - immediately on the right, there should not be zero or more whitespaces and then a digit.

**NOTE**: versions before 9.6 would show an exception: `ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid`.